# Intermittent Null Pointer in Auth0 Spring Security (BearerSecurityContextRepository)

Tags: java, spring-security, auth0

My team is using Auth0 to secure all of our Spring Boot services. It works perfectly fine 99% of the time, however one of our services fails with a null pointer when it receives requests.

This only happens during our CI builds when using a Linux build image and running @SpringBootTest tests against the service. On developer machines everything is fine, on a Windows build image everything is fine.

The failing service is identical in every way I can find to all our other services so this is quite a mystery to me.

The code that's failing is in BearerSecurityContextRepository in the Auth0 spring security library.

The code in question is this bit:

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
String token = tokenFromRequest(requestResponseHolder.getRequest());
Authentication authentication = PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationJsonWebToken.usingToken(token);
if (authentication != null) {
    context.setAuthentication(authentication);
    logger.debug("Found bearer token in request. Saving it in SecurityContext");
}
```

The context object on line 5 is coming back null and blowing up. I've looked at every possible implementation of the SecurityContextHolderStrategy that SecurityContextHolder could use that is on the classpath and I cannot see any scenario where that createEmptyContext() call would come back null. Every implementation seems to just return a new SecurityContextImpl.

It seems to me that it has to be something in the environment on this linux build image that's causing the problem (later parts of our build require us to use Linux or I'd just switch to a Windows image).

I'm hoping someone that knows the internals of spring security really well could give me some hints as to what might be causing the problem so I can dig deeper into the image. Or if I'm off base and it's something else, a pointer to what would be a life saver.

Thanks!